# Divs not showing specified height or width

Tags: css, html

I am trying to have 4 divs with different background colors in a container div so there is one in all four corners with a steelblue border cross in the middle. The problem is that I give the div elements width and height in my stylesheet, but they don't actually change the height of the div, only adding content does. Also, the 4 inner divs do not have the width I specified in the stlyesheet, but rather fit to the width of the parent div. Just fyi, in the feature class, I have switched the display attrubute to block and inline to see if that helps, but it doesn't. Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Divs In Div</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="feature a">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="feature b">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="feature c">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="feature d">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

and here is my css code:

```
.container {
width: 700px;
height: 700px;
border: 5px solid black;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: inline-block;
}

.feauture {
width: 348px;
height: 348px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

.a {
background-color: yellow;
border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}

.b {
background-color: red;
border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
border-left: 2px solid steelblue;
}

.c {
background-color: blue;
border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}

.d {
background-color: purple;
border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
border-left: 2px solid steelblue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, yes there's a typo, but that's not gonna solve the **whole** issue for you (although you haven't asked about the rest yet so this might just be unnecessary and if so, feel free to ignore).

HTML needs to be changed if you want to use `inline-block` for the `.feature` blocks.  [See why this is a problem here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).  If you're ok with using `float:left;` for them all instead then you don't have to do this.

Depending on whether you choose to use `box-sizing` for all the elements you have (like with a [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) solution or just doing what I do in my fiddle), you'll need to possibly change the width and height to account for the border only on the container.  [See how, why and pros/cons here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) on `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Your CSS isn't terrible so the changes I made were mainly aesthetic but the main thing you gotta decide is `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` inside of `.feature { }`.

*FYI - using `float: left;` implies `display: block;`, not to mention `<div>` using it by default.*

---

## Using `display: inline-block;`

### New HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div class="feature a">
    &nbsp;</div><div class="feature b">
    &nbsp;</div><div class="feature c">
    &nbsp;</div><div class="feature d">
    &nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

### New CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 710px;
    height: 710px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.feature {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.a {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}
.b {
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-left: 2px solid steelblue;
}
.c {
    background-color: blue;
    border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}
.d {
    background-color: purple;
    border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-left: 2px solid steelblue;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yFFN4/)

---

## Using `float: left;`

### New HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="feature a"></div>
    <div class="feature b"></div>
    <div class="feature c"></div>
    <div class="feature d"></div>
</div>
```

### New CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 710px;
    height: 710px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.feature {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.a {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}
.b {
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-left: 2px solid steelblue;
}
.c {
    background-color: blue;
    border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}
.d {
    background-color: purple;
    border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-left: 2px solid steelblue;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EKLFg/)

---

PS - your widths and heights are changed here for continuity but you can use whatever sizes you want that fit.

Answer (score 1):

```
.feauture {
```

Should be

```
.feature {
```

Comment: Thank you. When I open the file, the divs are all on top of each other on their own line. To have 2 inline, the largest width and height I can make them is 346px even though I should be able to make them each 348px since they have no padding, no margin, and a border of 2px but only on 2 sides and they have to fit in a container div of width 700px. When the width and height are set to 346px, there is a gap between the borders in the middle about 6px long and a margin at the bottom the same size between the 2 divs (class c and d) and container div. How do I make all the borders touch?

Comment: @user1953907 I'm guessing you meant to ask me that on my answer (hence the late response).  But this is most easily done using a hard size on the container with soft inner sizes (percentages).  Take a look at this fiddle I altered:  http://jsfiddle.net/5dg4X/  This makes .feature use a float with a max-width of 50% (setting the width to 100% so it maxes out that 50% allowance) so there's always 2 on a line and with the box-sizing set to border-box you can set your borders however big or small you want and the size will be included in the width.